# Is there a way to measure the memory usage of other iOS applications?

Tags: ios, instruments

From instruments, I found my app uses ~65mb in the foreground and ~60mb in the background.  I want to get a benchmark on how much memory other applications are using so that I can compare.

However when trying to attach the debugger to other application, no data comes though on instruments.  I think this is by design.

Is there any other way to determine how much memory other apps use?

The motivation comes from a slide in [WWDC 2015 - 213 - cocoa touch best practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=231).

[image]

Comment: Instruments has a profiling template called "System Trace". It provides you with a peek into all of the system calls that are happening on your device. It also gives you info about VM operations. I don't know for certain if it will give you what you want, but there are many things in Instruments that admittedly don't know how to do. It might be worth a look.